# No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new here.

In my Android app, there is an error while compiling the app. I am using Firebase Auth and Firebase Realtime Database. I followed the manual on the Firebase official site. But why I am getting this error. I tried a few days, but I can't.

Thanks for the helper in advance.

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.login_firebase, PID: 7570
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.login_firebase-feIFWbmL-7o_vW0RzlufbA==/base.apk)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

These are the codes I added to Android Studio.

**Bulid.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

**Bulid.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 29
      buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.login_firebase"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }

  }

  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase SDK versions don't match at all.  Set them so that they match the latest versions that you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions).  You should update them over time so they stay up to date.  You should also remove firebase-core, since it's no longer needed.

```
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

Comment: Maybe firebase does not required [firebase-core](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#firebase-bom) library as it's written in docs

Comment: The page I linked to says "The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics".  If you find something in the documentation confusing, use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page.